# React render callbacks over higher order components

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

React 'render callback's  or children function seem like the next new thing in the React world. Why would one prefer that over a higher order component? (Aside from the nice inline syntax, which comes at a performance cost) Does it solve any of the problems with hoc's ?

With the `render callback` pattern I mean the following:

```
const Width = ({ children }) => children(500)
<Width>
  {width => <div>window is {width}</div>}
</Width>
```